# Spring Cloud Gateway GlobalFilters are not executing when RedisRateLimiter blocks a request

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway, rate-limiting

I have implemented a global prefilter and a global postfilter to log the request events. I also have used a RequestRateLimiterFactory filter with RedisRateLimiter to avoid requests peaks that might overwhelm the service.

I want to use my pre and post filter to log two events.

1. A request from apiKey X has been noticed
2. The request has been either accepted or rejected by the rate limiter.

When the rate limiter accepts a request and forwards it, there is no problem, the pre and post filter execute and I can get to log the data I need.
The problem is that when the rate limiter blocks a request, neither the pre nor the postfilter are being executed so I cannot log or retrieve this event for metrics.

Even though spring cloud gateway works through a chain of filters I think that the problem above described may be caused by the isAllowed method from the RequestRateLimiterFactory class. This method sets completed the request when it is rejected instead of passing the exchange to the next filters. But I have been reasearching, and I did nothing useful to solve this problem.

```
return limiter.isAllowed(routeId, key).flatMap(response -> {

            for (Map.Entry<String, String> header : response.getHeaders().entrySet()) {
                exchange.getResponse().getHeaders().add(header.getKey(), header.getValue());
            }

            if (response.isAllowed()) {
                return chain.filter(exchange);
            }

            setResponseStatus(exchange, config.getStatusCode());
            return exchange.getResponse().setComplete();
        });
```

Comment: Let's correct terms what you used:  RequestRateLimiter, isAllowed, RequestRateLimiterFactory, etc.

Comment: If you meant to edit and correct the question I edited it trying to correct all terms, if you have any more suggestions about the post I will gladly edit it again, if you have a possible solution I will be even more grateful.